# Elixir Postgrex using uuid

Tags: elixir

I am using Postgrex library for my database, and I have the following problem: one of the columns in the database is of type `uuid`. I am using the UUID module in elixir but whenever I try to persist something to the database I get the following error: `Postgrex expected a binary of 16 bytes, got "3c5fda26-ea3b-4c77-8f19-06e106a61eda"`. I have tried to store it as 
a plain string but it was not possible as you can see. How should I convert the uuid before persisting it to the database?

Comment: Would you provide a command you are using to persist the record?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have just found that the UUID module has already a function called `UUID.string_to_binary!` , and its better to use this one instead of Ectos', as I am not using Ecto at all

Answer (score 5):

UUID is a string, but not a "human readable string". What you see as `3c5fda26-ea3b-4c77-8f19-06e106a61eda` is **not** UUID, it is only one of the possible human readable representations. What you need is to pass direct, internal, UUID representation which in fact is binary of 16 bytes. To parse string form it hexadecimal representation to binary representation you can use [`Ecto.UUID.dump/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/3.0.1/Ecto.UUID.html#dump/1).

Answer (score 3):

Set the type of the field as **binary_id** in the schema.

For Example:

```
@primary_key {:id, :binary_id, autogenerate: true}
@derive {Phoenix.Param, key: :id}
schema “companies” do
 field :name, :string
 field :mission_statement, :string

 has_many :managers, EctoUuid.Manager
 timestamps
end
```